# Firebase - How can I implement a login using only a username (no password/email)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating a webapp for a class assignment and would like to create a login with only a username. I've tried pushing just a username to the database, but it gets pushed as a child to the connection ID in Firebase. Here is the Javaascript I have created so far:

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var database = firebase.database();

var connectionsRef = database.ref("/connections");
var userRef = database.ref("/users")
var connectedRef = database.ref(".info/connected");

connectedRef.on("value", function (snap) {
    // If they are connected..
    if (snap.val()) {
        // Add user to the connections list.
        var con = connectionsRef.push(true);
        // Remove user from the connection list when they disconnect.
        con.onDisconnect().remove();
    }
});

var database = firebase.database();
var username = "";

$("#submit").on("click", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    username = $("#username").val().trim();
    userRef.push({
        username: username
    });

    $("#login-screen").attr("class", "hidden");
});
```

I plan on allowing the user to maintain their stats after leaving the page, so I figured assigning them to a username would be the way to go. If there are better ways to go about this, please let me know.

Comment: @Reverics did my answer solve your problem?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to try it out yet, but your answer makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Do comment if it poses any problem, Happy to help. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a separate node in your database with name `usernames` and store all the usernames of your users in there.

And for checking a right login, you can run a check in that child looking for the username your user entered, and if it matches with any of them, you can grant them login access.

Attaching a `value` observer to a list of data will return the entire list of data as a single snapshot which you can then loop over to access individual children.

```js
ref.once('value', function(snapshot) {
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
         var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
         var childData = childSnapshot.val();
         // ...
      });
});
```

Read more about this in [docs here.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events)

You can also use `on('value', ...)` as you would for a child event.